# База данных для программы

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, requests

Суть в том что у меня появилась потребность написать приложение, которое будет работать с базой данных. Условие в том, что база данных должна быть не локальная а сетевая. Я так понимаю что видимо где-то на хостинге надо ее распологать? Я планирую обращаться к ней через запросы, но вот сколько сервисов не смотрел, везде тредуется прописывать IP для доступа. Так как приложение может быть у кого угодно, то все айпишники не пропишешь.

Помогите мне советом, как к своему приложению прикрутить базу данных, к которой приложение сможет обратиться от куда угодно без всяких заморочек

Comment: Очевидно, вы не в курсе, как это работает. Ваши рассуждения неверны. Если кратко, то для подключения к серверу БД нужно знать его адрес. Сам же сервер может принимать подключения откуда угодно. Советую вам изучить подробнее, как это работает. А вопрос ваш настолько абстрактный, что на него невозможно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Да, вы парвы. Я и правда первый раз сталкиваюсь с задачей такого рода. Поэтому и пишу тут, что бы знающие люди дали мне подсказку.

По поводу адреса сервера я уже узнал, и тестировал подключение к БД на TimeWeb. Там надо указывать доступы по IP. Когда прописываю, то могу обращаться к базе. Когда удаляю свой IP, то доступ пропадает. Поискал еще некоторые хостинги которые предоставляют БД, там такая же система.

Если я не прав в своих рассуждениях, то подскажите тогда, как действовать в случае, когда нужна программа, которая заполняет единую БД с множества разных компьютеров?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, я понимаю, о чем идет речь.

Смотрите.

На хостинге timeweb используется mysql.

Для доступа к этой базе традиционно при создании пользователя добавляется ip-адрес, с которого можно обращаться к базе.

Обычно это делается командой типа

`grant all privileges on *.* to 'konst'@'109.252.65.30';`

Вообще говоря, можно сделать возможным доступ к базе с любого адреса:

`grant all privileges on *.* to 'konst'@'%';`

но я не знаю, позволяет ли сделать это интерфейс timeweb.

Но предыдущий отвт тоже правильный, просто сделать трехзвенную архитектуру для начинающего - это, конечно, сложнее, чем просто использовать "двузвенку", где приложение обращается к базе напрямую.

**Дополнение, написанное после уточнения вопроса**

> Моя задача стоит в том что бы написать приложение логирования работы компьютера для своей организации

Если речь идет о локальной сети - то можно поставить сервер базы данных в той же самой локальной сети. При этом у Вас пропадёт проблема с ограничениями timeweb для базы данных, но останется еще несколько проблем: нужно будет, чтобы Ваше приложение запускалось одновременно с включением компьютера, работало всё время и периодически обновляло базу, подавая сигнал "эй, я - компьютер с таким то IP и иименем - еще живой!". В по настоящему серьезном случае имеет смысл - для windows - написать так называемый windows service _ сервис, который работает под системный экаунтом, независимо от того, 'вошел' ли пользователь.

А потом Вам понадобится вторая часть программы - которая анализирует эту базу.

Как задача для разработки, на которой можно учиться и вообще совершенствоваться - это неплохая задача.

Но, если возиться не хочется - есть готовые решения для мониторинга. На память сразу приходят zabbix monitor и моя любимая - [PRTG network monitor tool](https://www.ru.paessler.com/prtg) (бесплатная для небольших сетей)

Comment: Интерфейс таймвеба этого не позволяет. И сколько я не находил сервисов, никто не позволяет. Как я писал ответом выше на комментарий, то мое приложение черезчур малофункциональное что бы создавать для нее сервер. Моя задача стоит в том что бы написать приложение логирования работы компьютера для своей организации.

Comment: @МаркСинельщиков - я дополнил свой ответ

Comment: ТС, вам нужно какое-то централизованное хранилище данных для решения этой задачи. Значит вам в любом случае понадобится сервер. В качестве альтернативы - только блокчейн :D

Comment: Да, про сервис я тоже думал и даже делал, но вернулся на WinForm приложение. Готовое решение не хочу использовать, так как хочу самостоятельно делать и в процессе учится чему-то новому)

Я так понимаю что мой запрос по простому подключению софта к БД либо очень глуп и никто так не делает, либо того что я хочу сделать, просто нельзя сделать)

Comment: Не знаю насколько меня все поняли, но я просто хотел сетевую базу, куда будет приложение записывать данные (не в одной локальной сети). Просто я уже разобрался как работать с сетевой базой, но не смог найти подходящую базу... А заморачиваться с клиент-серверным приложением, плюс разворотом БД на собственном сервере и дершать сервер онлайн 24\7 сильно сложный вариант для такой примитивной задачи. 

На данный момент в моем приложении 100 срок всего и оно адлекватно работает) а разработка трехзвенной архитектуры увеличит общий код в 10 раз

Comment: @МаркСинельщиков, а как Вы в итоге поступили с базой данных? на каком то хостинге запустили?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть применена "Трёхуровневая архитектура":

- программа-клиент
- программа-сервер
- база

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Трёхуровневая_архитектура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

Программа-сервер может отвечать за уровень логики / безопасности (не давать клиентам делать и смотреть в базе что угодно).

Программа-сервер предоставляет API для клиентов.

Есть средства упрощения разработки API, например gRPC.

Comment: Да, об этом я уже наслышан. Но мой проект очень приметивен что бы делать такую сложность. Плюс сервер-приложение должно где-то быть всегда открытым.

Приложение просто логирует активность компа и все. (Вкл компа, выкл компа, начало афк, конец афк). Поэтому я думал использовать примитивный вариант пямой записи в БД